# After response.write screen does not get updated

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a Purchase Order PDF  at the click of a button using Response.Write.

```
    Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PurchaseOrder.pdf");
    Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.ToArray().Length);
```

After that, I try to update the screen to show that the order has been raised:

```
    labelReqPOStatus.Text = "PO Raised";
```

The screen does not get updated. How can I get it to do so?

Comment: Is ms a memory stream? If so do you set the position on it to 0 before calling ToArray()? also Response.End() may help

Comment: You simple cannot do that ! Same answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760154/response-transmitfile-nothing-happening/14760372#14760372

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Aristos - this is not possible. What you can do is to

1) update your page first

```
labelReqPOStatus.Text = "PO Raised";
```

2) as part of this update add javascript code to start download of actual pdf (assuming you have "Handler1.ashx" that will serve the file like you've mentioned)

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Download", "window.open('Handler1.ashx')", true);
```